# Select options from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, html-select

I want a select/ dropdown menu with its options coming from the database using mysql select query.

**PROBLEM:** the dropdown menu displays the correct number of items inside the database but is not showing those items, just a blank option. e.g: there are four items in the database the dropdown menu has four blank options in it.

```
<label for="category">Category</label><select name=cat><option value=""> --Select Category-- </option>
    <?php $sql= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category FROM taxonomy");
        while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo "<OPTION VALUE='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</OPTION>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
echo "<OPTION VALUE='".$row[0]."'>".$row[0]."</OPTION>";
```

to

```
echo "<OPTION VALUE='".$result[0]."'>".$result]."</OPTION>";
```

Answer (score 1):

in $result add this

```
 mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_BOTH)
```

and

```
$result[0] instead $row[0]
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: No need to add MYSQLI_BOTH, it is the default value.